# How can I disable certain services and run only the ones I need in JBoss?

Tags: java, jboss, jndi

So I am new to JBoss and this might seem a little too trivial, but here goes. I have a downloaded version of JBoss on my remote and I basically want to start a cluster of HA-JNDI using the `all/deploy/cluster` directory. But what confuses me is what tells JBoss to run only the HA-JNDI cluster when I start JBoss? I have the `hajndi-jboss-beans.xml` to configure the HA-JNDI, but what if I do not want to start similar JBoss services. What do I have to do to achieve that? Please let me know if you need any other information. Thanks!

Comment: Note that there exist several versions of JBoss and each version has its own peculiarities when it comes to configuration, installation etc. Always mention the version(s) of the products you use and it if exists add the tag with the appropriate version(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the `{JBoss}/server/all` server as a template for creating JBoss instances, since it is set up for clustering.
2. Copy the `/all` server as a new server (i.e: `{JBoss}/server/ha`).
3. Make configuration changes, such as removing unneeded JBoss services
   (see [JBoss Application Framework Trimming guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Platform.94/ATGInstallGuide/html/s0903jbossapplicationframeworktrimmin01.html)).

Comment: Since weblinks can be removed in the future it is best to expand on them a little by providing a summary.